# How to write to socket after end of input stream?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm trying to write a very simple node TCP server which reads in the full input stream and writes out some function of the input. The output cannot be generated without the *full* input so the writes cannot be streamed as the input comes in. For simplicity sake in this post, I have omitted the actual transformation of the input and am just writing back the input.

My initial attempt was to write within the `end` event handler:

```js
const net = require('net');

const server = net.createServer(async client => {
  let data = '';

  client.on('end', () => {
    client.write(data);
  });

  client.on('data', part => {
    data += part.toString();
  });

  client.pipe(client);
});

server.listen(8124);
```

But this results in a `Socket.writeAfterFIN` error "This socket has been ended by the other party" which led me to enabling `allowHalfOpen` because [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_end) seem to indicate that it separates the incoming and outgoing `FIN` packets.

```js
const net = require('net');

const drain = client =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    let data = '';

    client.on('end', () => {
      console.log('end');
      resolve(data);
    });

    client.on('data', part => {
      console.log('data');
      data += part.toString();
    });
  });

const server = net.createServer({ allowHalfOpen: true }, async client => {
  const req = await drain(client);
  client.end(req);
});

server.listen(8124);
```

This works when I use e.g. `echo 'abc' | nc localhost 8124`, but I'm not sure whether `allowHalfOpen` should be necessary here. Is there another way to write shortly after the end of the input stream?

Comment: Why are you using `allowHalfOpen` and what are you trying to accomplish by using it?

Comment: My intention with `allowHalfOpen` is to provide more separation between the inflow of the stream and the outflow. In the actual implementation, there's more `client.write` calls that happen between `drain` and `client.end` based on the `req`.

Comment: I posted an answer I found, but I'll hold off on accepting it for a bit in case `allowHalfOpen` is the wrong approach here or if someone wants to offer a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: That's not what `allowHalfOpen` is for, and it's difficult to see why you think it will help in this situation. And soeicislly you can't use half-open with HTTP.

Comment: I did switch to netcat and that allows it to work, but it sounds like I shouldn't be using `allowHalfOpen`. I have edited the question to clarify my requirements and why I enabled that option.

Answer (score 0):

Using netcat instead of `curl` resolves the issue. e.g. `echo 'abc' | nc localhost 8124`. This is also more in line with what I need to do anyway since I don't need HTTP for this server.